# tried to merge system reserved partition with main and now cannot boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I had merged the system partition and main partition which is more or less structured as follows:

[image]

However, the merge didn't complete.  Thankfully, the data on the data partition still appears to be intact.  However, it will not boot.

I had tried to go into diskpart and set the data partition to be active as described here https://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/ to no avail.

I then tried to rebuild the bcd using bootrec but was getting an `access denied` message when running `bootrec /fixboot`.  I found running `bootsect/nt60 sys` helped get me past that and now I'm stuck at seeing a message saying that `windows\system32\drivers\atapi.sys` is missing.  However, when I run command line from my install dvd, I see the file right there. I was wondering how I can convince my drive to see that and presumably other files it may consider missing.

Unfortunately, due to the age of the computer, I don't believe the BIOS supports GPT partitions and I am stuck with using the MBR partition scheme.  A few resources I used include
https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/#Fix_the_MBR_in_Windows_10
https://neosmart.net/wiki/bootrec/#bootrec_RebuildBcd_doesn8217t_work

I've tried to practice doing this in a sandbox by spinning up a vm with windows 10 home installed and going through the same destructive process of merging and recovering, except here, the merging was successful.  At any rate, after going through the steps in the neosmart links above and then finally running "repair startup" or an option that's similar to that when booting into the windows 10 install dvd, I was able to recover boot capabilities.  I wasn't able to reproduce this on the original drive though.

One thing that might impact this is that I now recall that I assigned the drive letter to something else per instructions I read here: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied-error-on-windows-10 .  Perhaps that's why `atapi.sys` cannot be found?  How would I be able to see if there's any sort of drive letter alignment that needs to happen?  I would have figured that the path would be drive letter agnostic but rather based on the results of the windows installation I select after running `bootrec /rebuildbcd`.

Comment: First question: why? Messing with partitions is something you do carefully, and merging a reserved partition is a sure way to break things.

Answer (score 1):

The 500 MB NTFS System Reserved partition is nothing else than your EFI boot partition.

The merge process was enough to destroy the boot, so you will need to re-establish it.

You will need to
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

If you don't have a Windows Recovery USB or a Windows Installation boot media
*of the same Windows version as the one now installed*, you will need to create
it on another computer.